# "Syntax error or access violation: 1142" in Symfony and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

I am creating an API REST aplication with Symfony3, and I have this problem. When I execute the methods in localhost it works fine, but I have uploaded the project to a server administered with Plesk, and when I try to execute the methods with postman, it shows this:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.random_id AS ...'
>   with params [\"a\", \"a\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'app'@'localhost' for
>   table 'table_name'

It seems to be a permissions problem, but if I try to access to the database with MysQL Workbech, with the same credentials, I can do it and execute querys without problems. And in the Plesk panel, the user has all the permissions and privileges.

I have also tried changing "localhost" for the host address in the parameters file of Symfony.

Comment: post the code always

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `app` user doesn't have permissions to execute `SELECT` query.

Run following *MySQL* query to fix it:

```
GRANT SELECT on database_name.* to 'app'@'localhost' identified by 'your-pass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```